# VS2010 and VS2008 project compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know if VS2010 will use the same project & solution file format as 2008, or will the 2008 project files need to be upgraded to 2010 format before they'll open in that version?

Comment: Have a read of the following article on the Visual Studio blog. [Why does Visual Studio 2010 convert my projects?] http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/why-does-visual-studio-2010-convert-my-projects.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Visual Studio 2010 will allow you to move your projects from previous versions of Visual Studios  to VS 2010 with ease, I will call this process as “Converting” the project from VS 200X to VS 2010…

VS 2010 will also allow you to change your project’s Target Framework Version to .NET 4.0 from .NET 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5…  I will call this process as “Upgrading”…"

extracted from http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/05/vs-2010-project-conversion-upgrade.html

Comment: That's a bummer.  They did the same with 2005/2008 projects - made it tough to work on the same project in different versions of studio for testing.

Comment: VS 2005 could read VS 2008 project files, so you could have just created new solution files. I am hoping that I can get away with the same trick in VS 2010.

Comment: For C# projects, a VS2008 project file had to be modified in order for VS2005 to read it. A minor modification, but still a modification.

Comment: He's talking about keeping the older VS 2008/2005 project and .sln and other files from being upgraded but still work with them in vS 2010.

Answer (score 14):

I've just created a little [batch file that will convert between VS2008 and VS2010](http://cultiv.nl/blog/2010/3/16/convert-between-vs2008-and-2010-projects,-automatically) (vice versa) at will.

It rewrites the strings found at http://blogs.msdn.com/rextang/archive/2009/07/06/9819189.aspx between both versions in an automated fashion.

Comment: Thanks, it's pretty convenient as I'm still using VS2008 and more and more projects are in 2010.

Answer (score 11):

There is a trick.

1. Create a new Solution file.
2. Add all the existing projects, upgrading them in the process.
3. Use the old solution file in VS 2008 and the new one in VS 2010.

I did the same thing with VS 2005/2008 and didn't run into any problems.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem if the project files are under source control and the rest of the team is using VS 2008.

Comment: VS 2008 can read VS 2010 project files. It just can't read VS 2010 solution files.

Comment: Better yet, instead of creating a new solution file, just copy the original one.  Rename them to indicate which is 2008 and which is 2010.  Then open and upgrade the 2010.  The 2008 one will still work with VS 2008, even though the projects in it have been "upgraded".

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure I understand, I have done as Kyralessa said: VS2010 converted my projects and created new project files ending in vcxproj but VS2008 is not able to open those files. So how is the trick supposed to work because I don't mind having 2 solution files but I don't want to have 2 project files for each project.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do it with VC++ projects. I only used this trick on C# and VB.

Answer (score 6):

Well, there's a problem actually that you'll run into if you try to open a VS2010 project on a computer running only VS2008.

VS2010 makes changes to a MSBuild reference (.target-file) in the project file, and it can not compile in VS2008 if you don't change that reference back to the VS2008 default. But if you have both versions installed on the same machine it will work just fine.

So, you can have half you team install the VS2010 version without ever using it, and they can use VS2008 for whatever reason they want to.

*I'm unsure however how language specific feature to release 4.0 of the framework will work with VS2008, my theory is that the IDE won't take it all to well. So if you use C# but target both VS2008 and VS2010, avoid the new language features.*

Answer (score 3):

You could just have two different solution files. Usually in open source they make fx. project-2008.sln and project-2005.sln.

Comment: simplest solutions are always the best!

Comment: doesn't help if the projects were created in VS2010,

Answer (score 2):

to convert visual studio 2010 solution file (.sln) to visual studio 2008 solution file (.sln) simply follow these steps:

1. in .sln file replace "Format Version 11.00" to "Format Version 10.00"
2. in .sln file replace "# Visual Studio 2010" to "# Visual Studio 2008"
3. in .csproj replace "ToolsVersion=''4.0''" to "ToolsVersion=''3.5''"
4. in .csproj replace "v10.0" to "v9.0"

Answer (score 1):

VS2010 is going to be able to handle 2.0 through 4.0 framework projects, so if you have a project in one of those frameworks, it is unlikely that you would have to worry about any sort of updates or imports or anything of that sort to get up and running with current projects.

Comment: ya, that's a very generalized statement and won't work for everyone.  For example, when working with large teams you can't force everyone to upgrade to VS2010 just because one developer did.  There's licensing considerations also...

Answer (score 1):

Open solution file (.sln) in notepad and change
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00

## Visual Studio 2010

to
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00

## Visual Studio 2008

Then open the solution file from Visual studio 2008