# Portable VS 2008 Web Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to setup a VS 2008 Web Project in such a way that if some other developer wants to use VS 2010 (s)he can do it without affecting other developers. Can I do it by ignoring (svn:ignore or gitignore) some local IDE specific resources. Can you please point me to a guide, if this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely not.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/why-does-visual-studio-2010-convert-my-projects.aspx.  Also may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916190/vs2010-and-vs2008-project-compatibility